# How do I parse xml file with invalid character chode in xerces c?

Tags: c++, xml, xerces

I have a sample file below which can be parsed using C# code,
but when using xerces c it cannot parse due to invalid characters.
It can be parsed correctly only after removing ② and ①.
Is there a way to parsed this in xerces c?
(I am not inclined to using IBM xerces.)

Haha, it seems even stack overflow can also parsed it.
It displays correctly. But why not in xerces c?

```
<head>
<title/>
<script><![CDATA[
var b = "②";
]]>
</script>
</head>
<body style="background-color-index:7">
<p style="width:100px;height:100px;">①</p>
<p style="width:100px;height:100px;top:100px;">ｱｲｳｴｵ</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Try adding an XML declaration at the start of the file that declares the encoding. Without such a declaration, the parser has to try and guess the encoding, which isn't always possible. Also, you haven't told us what encoding you are actually using, and it might be one that Xerces-C doesn't actually support.

Comment: Yes it has xml declaration and encoding, hence when invalid chars were removed it can be parsed correctly. Sorry I forgot to mention that the xml has EUC-JP encoding which you are correct not supported by xerces c, but I wander why characters [ｱｲｳｴｵ] can be parsed correctly. Only ② and ① cannot be parsed.

Comment: As far as I can see from a quick scan of http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/EUC-JP/list.htm, the circled digits are not supported in the EUC-JP character set.

Comment: Ok, that is one big help. I am looking for XML4C which says supports EUC-JP. So I am looking for incorrect solution. With that, how could I parsed it without removing ② and ① on my xml content?

Comment: In my DTD validation file, I defined ① and ② as HTML entity HEX value. Then I use that defined value in replacement for the invalid characters(①②). It was parsed correctly. But I don't think this is the best solution. I cannot define all invalid characters in DTD file. Is there a way to catch all of invalid characters without defining them 1 by 1?

Comment: If you choose to use a character set/encoding that doesn't have a representation for all the Unicode codepoints in your document, then the only way to represent them is using numeric character entities. (But this doesn't require a DTD).

Comment: I think I was wrong when I said that it can be parse. Processing is successful but creating a node is not successful. I expected a node #text but there is none, it only created a node with name similar to my defined name but that node is empty. The output is it can display ｱｲｳｴｵ but not ①. I am not sure if I got your statement right [using numeric character entities], do you mean replacing invalid characters with its value? That is what I am pointing out, replacing them all will be work overload. Is there any other way to handle this all at once?

Comment: Sure, use an encoding that contains all the characters you want to use.

Comment: With current limitations on xerces c on encoding, any suggestions on how to use other encoding which will support the characters I needed?

Comment: Just use UTF-8 like most people do.

Comment: UTF-8 is already supported by xerces c. I want to know if there are other ways to support other encoding. Any link to download source with open source and license will do.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: sorry I want to parse the above content using xerces c, that is my goal.

Comment: Well you can't. Xerces C can only parse XML, and this isn't XML.